# How to do math operations on a dataframe with an undefined number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in which there is an indefinite number of columns, to be defined later.
Like this:

| index | GDP | 2004 | 2005 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| brasil | 1000 | 0.10 | 0.10 | ... |
| china | 1000 | 0.15 | 0.10 | ... |
| india | 1000 | 0.05 | 0.10 | ... |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['brasil', 'china', 'india'],
                   'GDP': [1000,1000,1000],
                   '2004': [0.10, 0.15, 0.05],
                   '2005': [0.10, 0.10, 0.10]})
```

Being the column GDP the initial GDP, and the columns from 2004 onwards being floats, representing percentages, relating to GDP growth in each year.

Using percentages to get the absolute number of the GDP in each year, based on initial GDP. I need a dataframe like this:

| index | GDP | 2004 | 2005 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| brasil | 1000 | 1100 | 1210 |
| china | 1000 | 1150 | 1265 |
| india | 1000 | 1050 | 1155 |

I tried to use itertuples, df.columns and for loops, but i probably missing something.

*Remembering that there are an indefinite number of columns.*

**Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: There are multiple ways to approach this.  Look at `df.columns` if you want to think just in terms of which columns to process. Using `df.melt` would be a more advanced approach. Check the docs.

Comment: You mean 0.05 for India not 0.5 as in code fragment. I used the corrected number in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a combination of Wardy and user19*.

Starting with...

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'GDP':   [1000, 1000, 1000],
                        '2004':  [0.10, 0.15, 0.5],
                        '2005':  [0.10, 0.10, 0.10],
                        'index': ['brasil', 'china', 'india']})
```

Find the percentage columns and make sure they are in the right order.

```py
columns_of_interest = sorted(c for c in df.columns if c not in ['GDP', 'index'])
```

Now we calculate...

```py
running_GDP = df['GDP'] # starting value
for column in columns_of_interest:
    running_GDP *= 1.0 + df[column]
    df[column] = running_GDP
```

This results in

```
    GDP     2004    2005    index
0   1000    1100.0  1210.0  brasil
1   1000    1150.0  1265.0  china
2   1000    1500.0  1650.0  india
```

Comment: A potentially better answer would be to use `sorted(c for c in df.columns if re.match('\d{4}', c))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.columns` to access a list of the dataframes columns.

Then you can do a loop over all of these column names. Here is an example of your data frame where I multiplied every value by 2. If you want to do different operations to different columns you can add conditions into the loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['brasil', 'china', 'india'],
               'GDP': [1000,1000,1000],
               '2004': [0.10, 0.15, 0.5],
               '2005': [0.10, 0.10, 0.10]})


for colName in df.columns:
    df[colName] *= 2

print(df)
```

this returns...

```
          index   GDP  2004  2005
0  brasilbrasil  2000   0.2   0.2
1    chinachina  2000   0.3   0.2
2    indiaindia  2000   1.0   0.2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to count the columns and loop over:

```
num = df.shape[1]
start = 2

for idx in range(start, num):
    df.iloc[:, idx] = df.iloc[:, idx-1] * (1+df.iloc[:, idx])

print(df)
```

which gives

```
    index   GDP    2004    2005
0  brasil  1000  1100.0  1210.0
1   china  1000  1150.0  1265.0
2   india  1000  1050.0  1155.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one to the percentages; calculate the cumulative product;

```
q = (df.iloc[:,2:] + 1).cumprod(axis=1)
```

multiply by the beginning gdp.

```
q = q.mul(df['GDP'],axis='index')
```

If you are trying to change the original DataFrame assign the result.

```
df.iloc[:,2:] = q
```

If you want to make new DataFrame concatenate the result with the first columns of the original.

```
new = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2],q],axis=1)
```

---

You can put those first two lines together if you want.

```
q = (df.iloc[:,2:] + 1).cumprod(axis=1).mul(df.GDP,axis='index')
```

Comment: There are typos and syntax errors in this code. It cannot be processed.

Comment: Sorry, I was on my mobile and didn't test it. There were other things wrong also. Thnx for pointing that out.